# Python: lists and copy of them

Tags: python, list

I can not explain the following behaviour:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l1[:][0] = 888
print(l1) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
l1[:] = [9, 8, 7, 6]
print(l1) # [9, 8, 7, 6]
```

It seems to be that `l1[:][0]` refers to a copy, whereas `l1[:]` refers to the object itself.

Comment: See [List - Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), especially assignment to slice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`l1[:][0] = 888` first takes a slice of all the elements in `l1` (`l1[:]`), which (as per list semantics) returns a new list object containing all the objects in `l1` -- it's a shallow copy of `l1`.

It then replaces the first element of that copied list with the integer `888` (`[0] = 888`).

Then, the copied list is discarded because nothing is done with it.

Your second example `l1[:] = [9, 8, 7, 6]` *replaces* all the elements in `l1` with those in the list `[9, 8, 7, 6]`. It's a slice assignment.

Comment: THanks for your answer. My point is that l1[:] seems to behave like a copy or like a reference to l1, depending on the fact I change a value or reassign the whole list.

Comment: It always makes a copy of `l1`, except when it's the target of an assignment (your second example), in which case it simply replaces the entire contents of `l1`.

Answer (score 13):

This is caused by python's feature that allows you to *assign a list to a slice of another list*, i.e.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l1[:2] = [9, 8]
print(l1)
```

will set `l1`'s first two values to `9` and `8` respectively. Similarly,

```
l1[:] = [9, 8, 7, 6]
```

assigns new values to all elements of `l1`.

---

More info about assignments in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).